# /dev/sdX changing every reboot | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, partitioning, do-release-upgrade

I upgraded the **Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04** After upgrading the OS all the mount point changing every reboot.

"/" actual mounted on "/dev/sda1" but If I reboot the system device name get changed "/dev/sde1" or "/dev/sdb1". How can I make that persistent?

Please see the below image which look like Before upgrade the OS :

[image: Before Upgrade OS Image]

After upgrade the OS 16.04 to 18.04 it's changing every reboot, please see the images :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can you help me to resolve this issue as I tried to reinstall the grub :

grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Please help me on this and this is happen with all 3 systems.

Comment: I can not see what you are saying. Please describe the issue not just show pictures.

Comment: Are all of your images from ONE system, or three different systems? Please focus on only one system, and remove the images that belong to other systems... otherwise there's no way for us to help. Do you have a USB flash drive connected? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab` and use text copy/paste... not screenshots please.

Comment: No, all images from one system, I am just showing that each reboot show different device name. Server is located in Azure Cloud.